# Calculate Percentage Within Grouping

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, common-table-expression

I'm trying to calculate the percentage of male and female from my tables; so far I have calculated the total number of females, males, and undisclosed from my table.  But then I want to calculate the percentage of female and males from these totals.

My initial query looked like:

```
SELECT   [description] AS [Gender] ,
     COUNT(C.id) AS [GenderCount]
FROM     dbo.Customers AS [C]
     INNER JOIN dbo.GenderTypes AS [GT] ON C.genderTypeID = GT.id
WHERE    C.customerStatusTypeID = 'O'
GROUP BY GT.[description]
```

And the results:

```
Gender      GenderCount
Female      60620
Male        394165
Undisclosed 630007
```

I have tried to wrap the query in a CTE to calculate the percentage using a case statement, but I'm obviously missing something because female, male, and undisclosed are all 100%.

```
;WITH Gender (Gender, GenderCount)
AS 
(
SELECT   [description] AS [Gender] ,
     COUNT(C.id) AS [GenderCount]
FROM     dbo.Customers AS [C]
     INNER JOIN dbo.GenderTypes AS [GT] ON C.genderTypeID = GT.id
WHERE    C.customerStatusTypeID = 'O'
GROUP BY GT.[description] )
SELECT Gender.Gender, Gender.GenderCount,
CASE WHEN
Gender.Gender = 'Female' THEN Gender.GenderCount / SUM(Gender.GenderCount) * 100
WHEN Gender.Gender = 'Male' THEN Gender.GenderCount / SUM(Gender.GenderCount) * 100
ELSE Gender.GenderCount / SUM(Gender.GenderCount) * 100
END AS [%Gender]
FROM Gender
GROUP BY Gender.Gender, Gender.GenderCount;
```

Here are the results:

```
Gender       GenderCount    %Gender
Female       60620          100
Male         394165         100
Undisclosed  630007         100
```

If my math/TSQL was correct, the results should look like:

```
Female: 5.59%
Male: 36.34%
Undisclosed: 58.08%
```

Could anyone help me on what I'm missing to get the correct results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the following query

```
DECLARE @SampleData AS TABLE
(
    Gender varchar(20),
    GenderCount int
)

INSERT INTO @SampleData
VALUES
('Female', 60620),
('Male', 394165),
('Undisclosed', 630007)

SELECT  *, 
       CAST(CAST(sd.GenderCount AS decimal)/sum(sd.GenderCount) over() *100 as decimal(10,2)) AS [%Gender] AS [%Gender]
FROM @SampleData sd
```

Returns

```
Gender  GenderCount %Gender
Female  60620   5.59
Male    394165  36.34
Undisclosed 630007  58.08
```

Your query could be written like this

```
;WITH temp as (
SELECT   [description] AS [Gender] ,
         COUNT(C.id) AS [GenderCount]
FROM     dbo.Customers AS [C]
     INNER JOIN dbo.GenderTypes AS [GT] ON C.genderTypeID = GT.id
WHERE    C.customerStatusTypeID = 'O'
GROUP BY GT.[description]
)
SELECT  *, 
        CAST(CAST(t.GenderCount AS decimal)/sum(t.GenderCount) over() *100 as decimal(10,2)) AS [%Gender]
FROM temp t
```

Comment: Awesome - I appreciate the help.

Comment: How would you limit the percentage of gender to 2 places after the decimal? Struggling to figure that out.

Comment: thanks - i was about to edit the comment as i finally figured it out.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this without need for a CTE:

```
SELECT   SUM(CASE WHEN GT.Gender = 'Female' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) * 100.00 / count(*) as FemalePercent,
         SUM(CASE WHEN GT.Gender = 'Male'   THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) * 100.00 / count(*) as MalePercent,
         SUM(CASE WHEN GT.Gender <> 'Male' AND GT.Gender <> 'Female'  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) * 100.00 / count(*) as UndisclosedPercent,
FROM     dbo.Customers AS [C]
         INNER JOIN dbo.GenderTypes AS [GT] ON C.genderTypeID = GT.id
WHERE    C.customerStatusTypeID = 'O'
```

This will give you a single row with the 3 percentages in separate columns.

If you need the results in a tabular format, your original query can be joined to another that gives the total number of records:

```
SELECT   GC.Gender,
         GC.GenderCount,
         GC.GenderCount * 100.00 / T.Total as Percentage
FROM
(
    SELECT   [description] AS [Gender] ,
             COUNT(C.id) AS [GenderCount]
    FROM     dbo.Customers AS [C]
             INNER JOIN dbo.GenderTypes AS [GT] ON C.genderTypeID = GT.id
    WHERE    C.customerStatusTypeID = 'O'
    GROUP BY GT.[description]
) GC
cross join
(
    SELECT Count(*) as Total
    FROM dbo.Customers C
    WHERE C.customerStatusTypeID = 'O'
) T
```

Comment: This works as well - I want to compare the plan vs. the answer posted above to see which one runs better on our system but I appreciate this answer.